# I want to install ipa from S3 bucket. its getting downloaded and trying to install. But installation getting fail

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-s3

I want to install ipa from S3 bucket. its getting downloaded and trying to install. But installation getting fail. like in app forced updation.

and my code is working fine. but installation getting failed.

while installing an alert is showing

> Cannot install applications because the certificate for (null) is not valid

```
`func S3Dowloadinstall(version: String) {
    let credentialProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: "keyR", secretKey: "keey")
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .region, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    let downloadFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(".ipa").path)
    let plistUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(".plist").path)
    let installURL = URL(string: "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=\(plistUrl.absoluteString)")
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, URL, data, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            try? data?.write(to: downloadFileURL)
            print("Downloaded to \(downloadFileURL.absoluteString)")
            print("Plist to \(plistUrl.absoluteString)")


            
            `let assetitem = ["kind":"software-package", 
            "url":downloadFileURL.absoluteString]
            let assets = [assetitem]
            let metadata = ["bundle-identifier":"  ", 
           "bundle-version":version, "kind":"software", 
            "title":"title"]
            let assetsnmeta = ["assets":assets, "metadata":metadata] 
        as [String : Any]
            let items = [assetsnmeta]
            let root = ["items":items]
            let plist = try? PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: root, format: .xml, options: 0)
            try? plist?.write(to: plistUrl)
            UIApplication.shared.open(installURL!, options: [:]) { (result) in
                if(result) {
                    print("Installing ...  \(installURL!.absoluteString)")
                } else {
                    print("Failed ...  \(installURL!.absoluteString)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    transferUtility.downloadData(
        fromBucket: "   ",
        key: "  ",
        expression: nil,
        completionHandler: completionHandler
    ).continueWith {
        (task) -> AnyObject? in if let error = task.error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return nil;
    }
}`
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that you download the file to the app's temporary directory, which is not accessible from "outside", e.g. the itms installer cannot access it.

Comment: changed the directory from temp to Documents, But same

Comment: Yes, all the directorys that your app accesses are sandboxed and not available to others. But you could check if this helps: https://www.bugsee.com/blog/ios-ad-hoc-distribution-using-amazon-s3/